# Cracking the Coding Interview — 1.5 One Away

Tags: algorithm, c, programming-challenge, edit-distance, c89

I would like to know any suggestions about to improve my code solution and your rating of my approach to the problem, I based my code on the fact that if the strings have different length removing one character from the longer string is equal to add one character to the shorter one.

**Description**

> One away : There are three types of edits that can be performed on
>   strings: insert a character, remove a character and replace a
>   character. Given two strings, write a function to check if they are
>   one edit (or zero edits) away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int helper_one_way(const char *str1, const char * str2, 
                          size_t len1, size_t flag) {
    size_t nchars = 0;
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len1; ++i, ++j) {
        if (str1[i] != str2[j]) { 
            if (++nchars > 1) return 0;
            if (flag && i) --i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/* check if str1 can be obtained from string2 adding, deleting, replacing
 * at last one char */
int one_way(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(str1), len2 = strlen(str2);
    size_t diff = abs(len1 - len2);

    if (diff > 1) return 0;
    if (!diff) return helper_one_way(str1, str2, len1, 0);
    if (len1 > len2) return helper_one_way(str2, str1, len2, 1);
    return helper_one_way(str1, str2, len1, 1); 
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", one_way("pale", "ple"));
    printf("%d\n", one_way("pales", "pale"));
    printf("%d\n", one_way("pale", "bale"));
    printf("%d\n", one_way("pale", "bake"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `adding, deleting, removing` what is the difference between the latter two items?

Comment: @greybeard: I meant replacing but I wrote removing, I updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally nice code: easy to read, good use of `const char*` for the string arguments.

---

It's great that we have unit tests; we can improve them by making them self-checking:

```
/* return number of test failures (0 or 1) */
int test_one_away(const char *str1, const char *str2, int expected)
{
    const int actual = one_way(str1, str2);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "one_way \"%s\", \"%s\" expected %d but got %d\n",
            str1, str2, expected, actual);
    return 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    return
        + test_one_away("pale", "ple", 1)
        + test_one_away("pales", "pale", 1)
        + test_one_away("pale", "bale", 1)
        + test_one_away("pale", "bake", 0);
}
```

---

We should add some more tests.  When I start writing tests (usually before the production code) I usually write the very simplest tests first, probably passing `NULL` to exercise the error recovery.  I'm going to assume that the code won't be testing for null pointers, but would certainly start with the next simplest case: are two empty strings within one change:

```
        + test_one_away("" "", 1)
```

Then compare one- and two-character strings against the empty string, and for strings that differ by one or two deletions at the beginning, middle and end.  A good guideline for testing functions that return a boolean value is to identify the boundaries where the result should change between false and true (e.g. remove one character from the front ⇒ true; remove two characters from front ⇒ false) and write one test for each side of that transition.

Here's a test that exposes a **bug** in the code:

```
        + test_one_away("pale", "ale", 1)
```

This is because we don't accept deletion of the first character:

> ```
>         if (flag && i) --i;
> ```

The fix is to remove the second part of the condition (remember, unsigned overflow is well-defined, and will exactly match the `++i` in the loop increment):

```
        if (flag) --i;
```

---

I'm not sure why `flag` needs to be a `size_t`;  a simple `int` should be sufficient.  If/when we have access to a C99 compiler (which should be soon; it's around 20 years old now), we could include `<stdbool.h>` and make it a `bool`.  It also needs a better name; I had to look to the call site to understand what it's for (it seems that a true value means that we're looking for a deletion rather than a replacement).

---

The conditions in the wrapper function could be expressed more clearly with a single `switch` on the difference in length:

```
/* check if str1 can be obtained from string2 adding, deleting, removing
 * at last one char */
bool one_way(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{

    size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);

    switch (len2 - len1) {
    case (size_t)-1: return helper_one_way(str2, str1, len2, true);
    case 0:          return helper_one_way(str1, str2, len1, false);
    case 1:          return helper_one_way(str1, str2, len2, true);
    default:         return false;
    }
}
```

---

We don't need to pass the length to `helper_one_way`, because it can simply stop when it reaches the terminating null char:

```
    for (i = 0, j = 0;  str1[i];  ++i, ++j) {
```

---

Given that we're iterating over strings, it's more idiomatic to use a char pointer than to repeatedly index into the string (though a good compiler ought to generate the same code):

```
static bool helper_one_way(const char *a, const char *b,
                           bool allow_deletion)
{
    size_t nchars = 0;
    while (*a) {
        if (*a++ != *b++) {
            if (++nchars > 1) return false;
            if (allow_deletion) --b;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Finally: the name - should `one_way` be spelt `one_away`?

---

## Modified code

Applying the above suggestions, we get:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool helper_one_away(const char *a, const char *b,
                           bool allow_deletion)
{
    size_t nchars = 0;
    while (*a) {
        if (*a++ != *b++) {
            if (++nchars > 1) return false;
            if (allow_deletion) --b;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/* Return true if a can be obtained from string2 by adding,
   deleting, or removing at most one character */
bool one_away(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    switch (strlen(a) - strlen(b)) {
    case (size_t)-1: return helper_one_away(b, a, true);
    case 0:          return helper_one_away(a, b, false);
    case 1:          return helper_one_away(a, b, true);
    default:         return false;
    }
}


/* Test code */

#include <stdio.h>

/* return number of test failures (0 or 1) */
static int test_one_away(const char *a, const char *b,
                         bool expected)
{
    const int actual = one_away(a, b);
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "one_away \"%s\", \"%s\" expected %d but got %d\n",
            a, b, expected, actual);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    return
        + test_one_away("", "", true)
        + test_one_away("", "a", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "", false)
        + test_one_away("pale", "le", false)
        + test_one_away("pale", "ale", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "pale", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "pal", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "pa", false)
        + test_one_away("pale", "ple", true)
        + test_one_away("ple", "pale", true)
        + test_one_away("pales", "pale", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "bale", true)
        + test_one_away("pale", "bake", false);
}
```

Comment: Great review, just one question: how you chose the strings being tested in the main() ?

Comment: Partly by reading the implementation ("*I wonder if we've tested that line when `flag` is true and `i` is zero?*") and partly by experience of known problem cases (empty strings, one-character strings).  The rest were just copied uncritically from the original.  For completeness, it might be worth having a test with a change (rather than insert/delete) of the first character, and of the last character.

Comment: Also, checking boundary conditions, where the result should flip from one to the other (e.g. remove one character from the front ⇒ true; remove two characters from front ⇒ false; no need to test three chars at front).

Answer (score 4):

1. Using a `size_t` for a boolean flag, and calling it `flag`, is nearly an obfuscation. Use `int` pre-C99 and call it something descriptive like `substitute`.
2. `strlen()` is likely a waste, though it makes describing the algorithm easier. Try to do without the additional iteration.
3. Getting the length of the longest common prefix looks like a well-defined task which can be extracted, and a useful building-block. Do so.
4. `one_way`, `one_away`, or `one_microsoft_way`? Having a properly-spelled correctly-selected name is Always very important.
5. Change to a single-traversal algorithm:

   Remove the common prefix.

   Measuring the common prefix without the first characters is quite instructive.

   With `x` and `y` different from `a`, call `n = strlen_common(++a, ++b)`:

   1. At most one substitution at the start:

      ```
      xaaaabcde
      yaaaabcde
      ```

      Result n == 8, a[n] == b[n].
   2. Deletion from the first:

      ```
      xaaaabcde
      aaaabcde
      ```

      n == 3, strcmp(a + n, b + n - 1) != 0
   3. Same way for deletion from second.

The modified code (also [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6f59e4e5790ae9)):

```
size_t strlen_common(const char* a, const char* b) {
    size_t r = 0;
    while (*a && *a++ == *b++)
        ++r;
    return r;
}

int one_away(const char* a, const char* b) {
    size_t n = strlen_common(a, b);
    a += n;
    b += n;
    if (!*a++)
        return !*b || !b[1];
    if (!*b++)
        return !*a;
    n = strlen_common(a, b);
    return a[n] == b[n]
        || !strcmp(a + n - 1, b + n)
        || !strcmp(a + n, b + n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Great review, as you described in the second point I will try your version without calling strlen().

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a suggestion on substance than a review of the code style; I'll leave that for other reviewers.

Your solution looks pretty good to me. I think you could streamline it a bit by doing it all in one shot, without checking the length of the strings first. For example:

```c
int one_way(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    int misses = 0, ia = 0, ib = 0, missed_index = 0;
    while (a[ia] || b[ib]) {
        /* Characters at this position match? Keep going... */
        if (a[ia] == b[ib]) {
            if (a[ia]) ++ia;
            if (b[ib]) ++ib;
        /* Mismatched characters? */
        } else {
            /* Already missed once; backtrack if skipped earlier, or bail. */
            if (++misses > 1) {
                if (missed_index) {
                    ia = missed_index;
                    ib = missed_index;
                    missed_index = 0;
                }
                else return 0;
            /* No misses yet... */
            } else {
                /* Skip buffer A ahead if its next char matches buffer B. */
                if (a[ia] && a[ia + 1] == b[ib]) {
                    ++ia;
                    missed_index = ia;
                }
                /* Skip buffer B ahead if its next char matches buffer A. */
                if (b[ib] && b[ib + 1] == a[ia]) {
                    ++ib;
                    missed_index = ib;
                }
                /* Skip both buffers ahead, if neither was skipped. */
                if (!missed_index) {
                    if (a[ia]) ++ia;
                    if (b[ib]) ++ib;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can test it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/B1C76fNZS

Comment: Try `"aa"` and `"ba"`. Sorry I gave you the wrong test-case.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for catching that, had a feeling this wasn't quite complete. I think you could probably add something like this to let the other iterator "catch up" after this situation happens: http://beta.pastie.org/iH3jbXzFRKhh ... but it's not exactly model clean code at this point. Will think about this a bit and edit or remove this answer later.

Comment: I took a different approach which also resulted in a single traversal.

Comment: @Deduplicator I *think* it's fixed now, but I'm not even sure at this point. I like your solution better now that this one's gotten hairy; yours is actually closer to what I had in mind initially.